# PHP mail only reaching certain clients

Tags: php, email, html-email, email-client

I've written a simple PHP HTML email form. That's all fine, it sends the email, the email doesn't get blocked. The problem with it is that only certain mail clients are receiving the emails: Gmail gets them fine, but another email account (used through a webmail client) doesn't, and neither do email apps I try. It appeared to work for a while after adding an `X-Mailer` header, but then stopped again; it also worked briefly when the recipients line was strangely formatted deliberately.

The form:

```
<form name="email" action="send.php" method="POST" id="mailform">
    * From: <input type="text" name="from" required/><br/>
    * To: <input type="text" name="to" required/><br/>
    * Reply-To: <input type="text" name="reply" required/><br/>
    Subject: <input type="text" name="subject" /><br/>
    * Message:<br/>
    <textarea name="email" rows="10" cols="100" id="message" required></textarea><br/>
    <input type="button" name="convert" id="convert" value="Convert and Check" />
</form>
```

(the 'Convert and Check' button is there because I use Markdown to format the HTML email; that part is again working fine. It changes to a Send button once the MD is converted to HTML.)

The PHP:

```
$from = $_POST["from"];
$to = $_POST["to"];
$reply = $_POST["reply"];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$message = $_POST["email"];
$headers = "Content-Type: text/html" . "\r\n"
    . "Reply-To: ".$reply . "\r\n"
    . "From: ".$from . "\r\n"
    . "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion() . "\r\n";
echo "<h3>Preview</h3><div class='content-container'>";
echo "<b>To:</b> ".htmlspecialchars($to)."<br/>";
echo "<b>Headers:</b> ".htmlspecialchars($headers)."<br/><hr/>";
echo "<div class='frame'>".$message."</div></div>";
echo "<br/><h3>Status</h3>";
$send = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if($send) {
    echo "Your mail was successfully accepted for delivery.";
}
else {
    echo "Sending of the email failed.";
}
```

Any ideas? It's got me confused - why do only some clients receive this?

Comment: Try sending mail through smtp .. also use some php library like phpmailer ..

Comment: @user574632: Of course it's behind authentication, yes. However, in previous PHP email scripts I've written, all clients have received it fine - **and those scripts still work**. So, there is something **in this script** preventing some clients receiving it.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Are saying that other php scripts, running on the same server, using the same mail server, can send to the same email address and the mail will be delivered, but not from this script?

Comment: @user574632 Precisely what I'm saying.

Answer (score 1):

because most of the email providers block emails from dynamic ips.

Comment: By 'dynamic' you mean 'changing periodically', I guess - the IP of that script doesn't change.

Comment: every not known ip is dynamic. a non dynamic ip is ips of well known email providers

Comment: How so? I have checked, the IP doesn't change.

Comment: that doesnt matter! you didnt bought that ip, its not yours, its your isps, the isp can issign it to anyone, that means its dynamic

Comment: Ah, I think I see the problem. This script is not on localhost, it's on a web server. That server is not under my ISP's jurisdiction.

Comment: ill say it shortly: many of the email providers have a list of verified ips (gmail knows yahoo,microsoft, etc..) and they wont receive emails from other ips